# Output mutiple array data with linebreak

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am working on a project and I want to display Order Item Quantity with Order Item Products.
Here is my function

```
<?php 
function wpallexport_order_items($value) {
$order = wc_get_order($value);
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $qty[]  = $item->get_quantity();
            $name[]  = $item->get_name();

            $q = implode($qty);
            $n = implode($name);
            $output = $q .' * '. $n .'<br>';
        }
        return $output;
}
?>
```

But it gives output format is

```
 158 * Macroni Pasta Honey
```

And I want Output like

```
1 * Macroni
5 * Pasta
8 * Honey
```

How to get the required output ?
Regards

Comment: Why are you creating arrays with a single string and imploding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = [];
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    // Collect all strings to one array
    $data[]  = $item->get_quantity() .' * '. $item->get_name();
}
// Then implode this array with `<br>` as glue
$output = implode('<br>', $data);

return $output;
```